# A Lie group representation where trace cannot send non-conjugate elements to the same thing

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups

Let $G$ be a Lie group and $g,h\in G$. Is there a representation (finite dimensional, over $\mathbb R$ is preferable but any other field (like $\mathbb C$) or if necessary, infinite dimensional representations will do) $\rho\colon G\to\mathrm{Aut}\left(V\right)$ such that
\begin{equation}
\mathrm{Tr}\left(\rho\left(g\right)\right)=\mathrm{Tr}\left(\rho\left(h\right)\right)\Longleftrightarrow\exists k\text{ such that }g=khk^{-1}
\end{equation}

Comment: The Stone-von Neumann theorem says this is very false for unitary representations of the Heisenberg group.  Not sure about arbitrary representations though.  Another place to look is at say the universal cover of $SL_n(\mathbb{R})$, which has no faithful finite dimensional representations so it also fails there.  With infinite dimensional things you don't really have a good notion of trace so it's not clear what an infinite dimension example would even mean.

Comment: @Nate, by infinite-dimensional trace, I assumed that $\rho$ maps into trace-class operators.

Comment: Do such representations even exist?  Shouldn't the inverse of a trace-class operator not be a trace-class operator?

Comment: @Nate, yes you're right, they can't exist. What about a different class function? Is there some sort of universal class function? In the sense that $c\left(g\right)=c\left(h\right)$ if and only if there is a $k$ such that $g=khk^{-1}$.

Comment: Another problem is that it is possible for a conjugacy class to contain another in its closure. For example in $GL_2(\mathbb{C})$ the matrices with top row $(1,\epsilon)$ and bottom row $(0,1)$ are all conjugate, but the identity is clearly in the orbit closure.  In particular this means that any continuous class function will have to agree on both conjugacy classes.